# Is there a performance problem if I run apache on multiple ports for various domains?

Tags: performance, apache-2.2, nginx

I have two domains right now. Both run on Apache and are behind nginx (using proxy_pass).

One site is django and another is php and both are running on different ports.

I want to deploy more domains in similar fashion, however is running apache on multiple ports for different application a bad practice ?

If yes/no, why ?

Comment: This looks similar to this:http://serverfault.com/questions/251593/proxying-to-the-same-server-on-multiple-ports but it's not quite, so I migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't see Apache listening on multiple ports a performance problem.

I have seen single applications use 1 instance of Nxinx to proxy_pass to multiple upstream apache servers.  Sounds like a good idea.